# splitting list in dataframe columns to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my data frame looks like as follows

```
    col1     col2     col3
0  [1, a]  [1, a1]  [1, a2]
1  [2, b]  [2, b1]  [2, b2]
2  [3, c]  [3, c1]  [3, c2]
```

I need to make it look like:

```
   col1     col2     col3  col4
0  a         a1      a2    1
1  b         b1      b2    2
2  c         c1      c2    3
```

---

My code

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1':[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']],
     'col2':[[1,'a1'],[2,'b1'],[3,'c1']],
     'col3':[[1,'a2'],[2,'b2'],[3,'c2']]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

so far I have tried using apply(pd.Series) and iterating through a for loop to reassign the values and have not had success

Comment: So for col1, col2, col3 : keep second value, and for col4 ?

Comment: yes, for col1 - col3 I need just the second value. col4 is a new col that has what the first vals in the other 3 columns was (every row in the original dataframe will have the same val in the the first spot).

Comment: @Just_Some_Guy What if first value in `col1` is `1` and in `col2` is `2` (in the same row)?

Comment: @AndrejKesely that should happen with the data I am working with; it should always be the same through all the columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way using `applymap` and `map`:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x[-1]).assign(col4 = df['col1'].map(lambda x: x[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments (the first value is the same across all columns in the row):

```py
print(
    df.apply(lambda x: [v[1] for v in x] + [x[0][0]], axis=1)
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns=lambda x: "col{}".format(x + 1))
)
```

Prints:

```
  col1 col2 col3  col4
0    a   a1   a2     1
1    b   b1   b2     2
2    c   c1   c2     3
```

---

Or:

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.transform(lambda x: [v[1] for v in x], axis=1),
        df.apply(lambda x: x[0][0], axis=1).rename("col4"),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  col1 col2 col3  col4
0    a   a1   a2     1
1    b   b1   b2     2
2    c   c1   c2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas' string methods to access the values :

```
(df.assign(col1 = df.col1.str[-1], 
           col2 = df.col2.str[-1], 
           col3 = df.col3.str[-1], 
           col4 = df.col1.str[0])
   )

  col1 col2 col3  col4
0    a   a1   a2     1
1    b   b1   b2     2
2    c   c1   c2     3
```

You could make it a bit more generic, by using a dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {col : df[col].str[-1] for col in df}
col4 = df.col1.str[0]
df.assign(**result, col4 = col4)
 
  col1 col2 col3  col4
0    a   a1   a2     1
1    b   b1   b2     2
2    c   c1   c2     3
```

You could very well dump it into python and create a new dataframe:

```
outcome = {key: [ent[-1] for ent in value] 
           for key, value in df.items()}
col4 = {'col4' : [value[-0] for value in df.col1]}
outcome = outcome | col4 # python 3.9, for earlier {**outcome, **col4}
pd.DataFrame(outcome)
 
  col1 col2 col3  col4
0    a   a1   a2     1
1    b   b1   b2     2
2    c   c1   c2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

A numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': {0: [1, 'a'], 1: [2, 'b'], 2: [3, 'c']},
    'col2': {0: [1, 'a1'], 1: [2, 'b1'], 2: [3, 'c1']},
    'col3': {0: [1, 'a2'], 1: [2, 'b2'], 2: [3, 'c2']}
})
a = np.array(df.values.tolist())

new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.concatenate((a[..., 1], a[:, 0, 0, None]), axis=1),
    columns=[*df.columns, 'col4']
)
print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a   a1   a2    1
1    b   b1   b2    2
2    c   c1   c2    3
```

---

Some timing information via perfplot:

[image: perfplot of various solutions runtime]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot


def gen_data(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'col1': [[1, 'a']],
         'col2': [[1, 'a1']],
         'col3': [[1, 'a2']]},
    )
    df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, n)]
    return df


def applymap(df):
    return df.applymap(lambda x: x[-1]).assign(
        col4=df['col1'].map(lambda x: x[0]))


def apply_series(df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: [v[1] for v in x] + [x[0][0]], axis=1) \
        .apply(pd.Series) \
        .rename(columns=lambda x: "col{}".format(x + 1))


def pd_concat(df):
    return pd.concat(
        [
            df.transform(lambda x: [v[1] for v in x], axis=1),
            df.apply(lambda x: x[0][0], axis=1).rename("col4"),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )


def str_accessors(df):
    return df.assign(col1=df.col1.str[-1],
                     col2=df.col2.str[-1],
                     col3=df.col3.str[-1],
                     col4=df.col1.str[0])


def str_accessors_generic(df):
    result = {col: df[col].str[-1] for col in df}
    col4 = df.col1.str[0]
    return df.assign(**result, col4=col4)


def dump_into_python(df):
    outcome = {key: [ent[-1] for ent in value]
               for key, value in df.items()}
    col4 = {'col4': [value[-0] for value in df.col1]}
    outcome = outcome | col4
    return pd.DataFrame(outcome)


def numpy_sol(df):
    a = np.array(df.values.tolist())
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.concatenate((a[..., 1], a[:, 0, 0, None]), axis=1),
        columns=[*df.columns, 'col4']
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = perfplot.bench(
        setup=gen_data,
        kernels=[
            applymap,
            apply_series,
            pd_concat,
            str_accessors,
            str_accessors_generic,
            dump_into_python,
            numpy_sol
        ],
        labels=[
            'applymap_map (rhug123)',
            'apply_series (Andrej Kesely)',
            'pd_concat (Andrej Kesely)',
            'str_accessors (sammywemmy)',
            'str_accessors_generic (sammywemmy)',
            'dump_into_python (sammywemmy)',
            'numpy_sol (Henry Ecker)',
        ],
        n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(18)],
        equality_check=None
    )
    out.save('perfplot_results.png', transparent=False)
```

Comment: nice timings. I suspect that if you do everything within python, you would get speedup that may be better than numpy. reason for my guess is they are lists/expense in converting to numpy, then accessing strings. of course, all that wont stand if the speed test returns something different

Comment: @sammywemmy your intuition was correct. Although applymap + map still seems to be the best solution.

Comment: nice.  learnt something new. applymap can be helpful in string processing/python dependent steps. thanks